# How do I find the time of a particular keyframe using cmds.selectKey?

Tags: python, animation, maya

I'm trying to find the time of a particularly selected key from the keys' animCurve node ("lastKey" in the code below). I can select my key using:

```
cmds.selectKey(lastKey, index=(1, 1))
```

However cmds.selectKey only returns the amount of keys selected. And there doesn't look to be a way in the command to query the key index time.

I've tried using cmds.keyframe, but my key is not on a particular attribute, it's a Set Driven Key.

```
print cmds.keyframe(lastKey, index=(1,1), query=True)
```

"None" gets returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know which object and/or attribute you are working on you can get the time like so:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

# Get index value of last key
keyIndex = (cmds.keyframe("myObject.attribute", indexValue=True, q=True))[-1]

# Get time of key index
keyFrame = cmds.keyframe("myObject.attribute", q=True, index=(1, keyIndex))
```

Does this work? `cmds.keyframe()` returns a list of time values of the queried keyframes.

A simpler way may be to simple query the keyframes of `lastKey` and then take the last element in the list, like so

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
keyFrame = (cmds.keyFrame("myAnimCurve", q=True))[-1]
```

This is assuming that lastKey only has one animCurve attached to it. Otherwise the list will be a bit more messy.

**EDIT FOR DRIVEN KEYS**

I just noticed the bit about the Driven Key. If the below is not what you're looking for, could you elaborate your question a bit?

If you have the animCurve, you can get a list of the **Driver** values like so

```
driverKeys = cmds.keyframe("myAnimCurve", q=True, floatChange=True)
```

And similarly, you can then get a list of the **Driven** values like this

```
drivenKeys = cmds.keyframe("myAnimCurve", q=True, valueChange=True)
```

Finally, you can simply take the last element in the list using `[-1]`

```
print(driverKeys[-1])  # return time of last driven keyframe
print(drivenKeys[-1])  # return value at last driven keyframe
```

*Note: The order of the list is based on the driver's values.*